# Remove a linked external website from my Google site search results

Tags: google-search

I have a website which has links to a external website. When I search on Google my website, search result contains the external website as well.

Is there any way possible that the external website do not show up when my website is searched?

Comment: We would need an example of what you mean. It is not clear to me. For example, How does *search result contains the external website as well* look in the SERPs? What search terms are you using? What are the domain names? How are you linking to the other site? Otherwise, there is not enough here to even guess.